# Parsing xml file using xpath and xquery

Tags: php, xpath, xquery

I have a xml file

```
<category>
    <type name="SWEATERS">
        <product id =1>
            <itemNumber>1</itemNumber>
            <name>ProductA2</name>
            <price>345</price>
        </product>
   </type>
   <type name="PANTS">
        <product id=2>
            <itemNumber>4</itemNumber>
            <name>Product Test </name>
            <price>456</price>
        </product>
    </type>
</category>
```

I used the xquery

```
$xml->xpath('//category/type/product[@id=1]');
```

The out put will give the itemNumber name and price.How i can get the type name i mean SWEATERS

Comment: `//category/type[@name="SWEATERS"]` ?

Comment: I want  type name with product id =1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this using the parent `..`, then the `@name` attribute.

```
$xml->xpath('//category/type/product[@id=1]/../@name');
```

[xPath Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `name` attribute of the type with a product element with an `id` of 1:

```
$xml->xpath('//category/type[product/@id=1]/@name');
```